# connection string to use both Model first, DB first for same database,

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Asp.net Entity framework, we use both Model first, DB first for same database, 
And there is two connection string for Model first, DB first.
So how can we create single connection string for both Model first, DB first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;
     Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;multipleactiveresultsets=true"

string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";    

EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlConnectionString;
entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/AdventureWorksModel.csdl|
                        res://*/AdventureWorksModel.ssdl|
                        res://*/AdventureWorksModel.msl";

string entityConnectionString = entityBuilder.ToString();
```

Or, if you are brave enought, you can try just reformat entityConnectionString:

```
string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;
     Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
     multipleactiveresultsets=true"

string entityConnectionString = 
  string.Format("metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl; provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='{0}'" providerName=\"System.Data.EntityClient\"",
    sqlConnectionString
 );
```

Edit:

Alternatively, you can take oposite approach, lets keep EntityConnectionString and extract SqlConnectionString from it:

```
string entityConnectionString = 'xxxxxxx';
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionString);

string sqlConnectionString = entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection strings will be different: the DB first one will have the metadata [embedded] location at the beginning. You could put the "normal" Code First connection string in the web.config and add the "metadata part" in the DB First DbContext constructor, using a static method to build the EntityConnectionString needed.

Example:

```
public MyContext() : base(BuildConnectionString())
{
}

private static string BuildConnectionString()
{
  varsqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
  //dinamically prepare the provider connection string here, using the CF one in the web.config 
  //[..]

  //now build the entity connection string, using the one just built as ProviderConnectionString
  var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
  entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();
  entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/";
  entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

  return entityBuilder.ToString();
}
```